# How do I use "date" function with case statement in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

[image: Date Image]

I have this case statement attached to a code. But it's not working as it should. It is bringing "false" in the (Treaty Column) instead of the respected Treaties assigned. My thought is, it's not recognizing the dates as "Date". Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong or how to apply the "Date" function to the case statement? Thank you!

```
set Reference_Org_Var = 'HII_STM';
set Load_Date_Var = current_date();
set Treaty_Var = ' ';

insert into PREMIUM_DB(Plan_Name, Member_ID, 
"3x2_Term", Member_Policy_Effective_Date,
Reference_Org, Treaty, LoadDt)

select Plan_Name, Member_ID, '3x2_Term', 
Member_Policy_Effective_Date,
FileRecdDate, $Reference_Org_Var, 
case
when Member_Policy_Effective_Date <= '2017-02-28' 
    then $Treaty_Var = '2016 Treaty'
when Member_Policy_Effective_Date between '2017-03-01' and '2018-02-28' 
    then $Treaty_Var = '2017 Treaty'
when Member_Policy_Effective_Date between '2018-03-01' and '2018-09-30' 
    then $Treaty_Var = '2018a Treaty'
when Member_Policy_Effective_Date between '2018-10-01' and '2018-10-31' 
    then $Treaty_Var = '2018b Treaty'
else $Treaty_Var = ' '
end,                                      
$Load_Date_Var

from HII_STM_PREM;
```

Comment: I’m not sure what you are trying to achieve here? You have an INSERT INTO…SELECT statement but then in the SELECT statement there is a CASE statement setting the value of a variable ($Treaty_Var) rather than providing a value to be inserted into the table. Doesn't make sense to me

Comment: @NickW I want the Treaty column to produce the respective treaties assigned along with the dates provided. For example If : Member_Policy_Effective_Date <= '2017-02-28' Then I want it to show (2016 Treaty) in the Treaty column. The query is running fine with no error. The issue is I don't think it's recognizing the dates as a date function.

Comment: Please provide sample source data, the expected results and the actual results you are getting (all as editable text, added to your question)

Comment: @NickW I am sorry Nick I am really new here and trying to find my way around. I don't have an idea of what you are requesting. However, I have attached an image of the sample data, with the current and expected result.  I also tried this code but it still wont work: when ("DATE"(Member_Policy_Effective_Date)  <= '02/28/2017') then $Treaty_Var = '2016 Treaty'

Comment: Hi - not a problem that you are new here. If you link to an image then no-one can copy the data into their own SQL tool to try out a solution, instead they would have to manually re-key it which most people don’t have time to do. So please paste your data as text into your question and format it as tables. You need 1) the data in the table HII_STM_PREM, 2) the results when you run your query against this data, and 3) the results that you want to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the value of your Treaty column to the result of an equality check, but you seem to actually just want the value on the right hand side which you can achieve by changing your query to use `THEN` statements to `THEN '2017 Treaty'` etc (instead of `THEN $Treaty_Var = '2017 Treaty'`)

```
set Treaty_Var = ' ';
WITH HII_STM_PREM as (select $1 Member_Policy_Effective_Date from VALUES ('2017-02-20'),
('2018-02-28'),
('2017-03-01'),
('2018-03-01'),
('2018-09-30'),
('2018-10-01'),
('2018-10-31'))

select
case
when Member_Policy_Effective_Date <= '2017-02-28' 
    then $Treaty_Var = '2016 Treaty'
when Member_Policy_Effective_Date between '2017-03-01' and '2018-02-28' 
    then $Treaty_Var = '2017 Treaty'
when Member_Policy_Effective_Date between '2018-03-01' and '2018-09-30' 
    then $Treaty_Var = '2018a Treaty'
when Member_Policy_Effective_Date between '2018-10-01' and '2018-10-31' 
    then $Treaty_Var = '2018b Treaty'
else $Treaty_Var = ' '
end current_val,
case
when Member_Policy_Effective_Date <= '2017-02-28' 
    then '2016 Treaty'
when Member_Policy_Effective_Date between '2017-03-01' and '2018-02-28' 
    then '2017 Treaty'
when Member_Policy_Effective_Date between '2018-03-01' and '2018-09-30' 
    then '2018a Treaty'
when Member_Policy_Effective_Date between '2018-10-01' and '2018-10-31' 
    then '2018b Treaty'
else ' '
end expected_val
from HII_STM_PREM;

CURRENT_VAL EXPECTED_VAL
FALSE   2016 Treaty
FALSE   2017 Treaty
FALSE   2017 Treaty
FALSE   2018a Treaty
FALSE   2018a Treaty
FALSE   2018b Treaty
FALSE   2018b Treaty
```